# Error: runtime:extensions~request: request url is empty Google OAuth with node.js and express cannot get authentication to work

Tags: node.js, express, postman, google-oauth, passport.js

I am trying to get Google OAuth to work with my node JS backend, I am using Passport JS with the google Strategy as well as the mongoose find or create package to find or create the user.

I am able to complete signin with the google browser popup when requesting an access token with postman.

callback URL is: http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google/callback

Auth URL is: http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google

The remaining detail is being passed in by passport.

Top Boilerplate code in my Subscribers route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Subscriber = require("../models/subscriber");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const Order = require("../models/order");
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;


router.use(session({
    secret: "foodsecrets",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());
passport.use(Subscriber.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(Subscriber.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Subscriber.deserializeUser());



passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: "330178790432-ro0cr35k37f7kq4ln4pdq6dqdpqqtri6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        clientSecret: "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",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google/callback",
        userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        Subscriber.findOrCreate({
            googleId: profile.id
        }, function (err, user) {
            return cb(err, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Routes for initial Auth and Callback:

```
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile"]
}));

router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        successRedirect: "http://localhost:3001",
        failureRedirect: "/login/failed",
    })
);
```

Subscriber Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate')




const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String
})

const favouritesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    favouritemeals: {
        type: Array

    },
    favouriteresturants: {
        type: Array

    }
})

const pendingItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String

})

const pendingOrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     userID: {
             type: String,
             required: true
         },
         total: {
             type: Number,
             required: true
         },
         items: [pendingItemsSchema],
         removeItem: {
             type: String
         },
         orderData: {
             type: Date,
             required: true,
             default: Date.now
         },
         confirmed: {
             type: Boolean,
             required: true
         }
})

const subscriberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    subscribeData: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    },
    orderHistory: {
        type: Array,
    },
    favourites: {
        favouritesSchema
    },
    cart: [cartSchema],
    login: {
        type: String,

    },
    pendingOrder: [pendingOrderSchema]
})



subscriberSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)
subscriberSchema.plugin(findOrCreate)

module.exports = mongoose.model("subscriber", subscriberSchema)
```

when I send the access token request from postman I login sucessfully and recieve the following error as well as the following detail

Error message in console:

```
Error: runtime:extensions~request: request url is empty
```

Request Detail:

```
POST
Error: runtime:extensions~request: request url is empty
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic Og==
Request Body
grant_type: "authorization_code"
code: "4/0AX4XfWjomz86Qs18ShaqLeJmQO13nTOzaz92dONTQgRUNQsuFj6ipIS6D5KFgjiWQtFkVg"
redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google/callback"
client_id: ""
```

I think there is something wrong with my callback route but I'm not really sure. This is my first time setting OAuth up so a bit clueless, any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, url is wrong.

Use `http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google/callback` (or)

```js
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: "330178790432-ro0cr35k37f7kq4ln4pdq6dqdpqqtri6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        clientSecret: "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",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google/callback", // fix this url
        userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
    },
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the url is the same one you are suggesting?

Comment: I see http://localhost:3000/subscribers/google/callback. Change it to one i suggested